# Sharing documents with partners in partner community

Tags: community, partner-portal, document, partner-communities

I have a partner community.
I'm not sure what is the best way to share documents with them e.g. using Documents, Files or Content.
I thought of using the Documents tab but even though the partner profile allows read of documents and the tab is On I cannot find it in the Portal's tab list.

What is the best way to share documents with Partners over the portal?
Any Advise?

Answer (score 2):

First, quick clarification, there is no such thing as a partner community or customer community any more as it was with portals. Salesforce communities can have members that are internal users, Chatter Free users, customer community users, partner community users, etc. all under one roof.

My best advice for document sharing within a community is to consider using Chatter and Chatter Files. Most of Salesforce.com innovation and energy over the past few releases has focused on making Chatter and the feed a primary place to share files and documents. The Files tab can be surfaced to a community in the Manage Communities config interface.

Comment: If we would like to have content in different folders etc. I assume chatter files does not support this

Comment: No, but it does support files associated with groups.

Answer (score 0):

Use content, if you want versioning and workspace capabilities of Content. Chatter files in turn use content, but with social features added. If you don't want any of these use documents.

Also check for the licences (it's salesforce CRM content user).

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed separate Customer Communities and Partner Communities.  You can see the differences here:  http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/free-trial-pricing/communities.jsp

Comment: While there are separate licenses, with different object permissions, and different access to the permissions structure there isn't a separate product. Customer community users and partner community users can be a part of the same community, with different levels of access.